# How can I print PHP POST data using AJAX? (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So basically I've got this HTML.

```
<form  method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="getData()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Form</legend>
<label>Color: <input type='text' id="color" name='color'></label>
<label><input type="submit"></label>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="showoutput">

</div>
```

This PHP:

```
<?php
$color = $_POST['color'];

    if($color != "")
    {
    $color = htmlentities($color, ENT_QUOTES);
    print "<p>The color is $color</p>";
    }
    else
    {
    print "<p>Fill out form!</p>";
    }

?>
```

And this JS:

```
window.onload = getData;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

function getData()
{
var poststr = "color=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("color").value );

req.open("POST", "lab11-1.php", true);
req.onreadystatechange = useResponse;
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

req.send(poststr);

}

function useResponse()
{
    if(req.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(req.status == 200)
        {
        document.getElementById('showoutput').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to be able to input a color in the form, hit submit, and use AJAX to print the PHP to the "showoutput" div in my HTML. I've tried everything I can think of and haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: What are you trying to acccomplish, you are missing two different ways of submitting a form. Do you want it to do it through AJAX? It works for me. Are you sure you have the lab11-1.php file in the same folder?

Comment: don't forget to add a `preventDefault()` on submit

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I was referencing my php file relative to the js file, not the html file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not correct.
Ajax don't need form submit function,

I did do like this, I think you want it.

```
<form  method="post" id="myform">
<fieldset>
<legend>Form</legend>
<label>Color: <input type='text' id="color" name='color'></label>
<label><input type="button" onclick="getData()" value="submit"></label>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="showoutput">

</div>
<script>
window.onload = getData;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

function getData()
{
var poststr = "color=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("color").value );

req.open("POST", "test.php", true);
req.onreadystatechange = useResponse;
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

req.send(poststr);

}

function useResponse()
{
    if(req.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(req.status == 200)
        {
        document.getElementById('showoutput').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```